# Unexpected value when performing simple arithmetic on int that was assigned a rounded float value in C

Tags: c

Hours of trying to figure this out have led to nowhere. I don't understand why the integer value of nickels is so high?

Please enter amount of change owed in $xx.xx format: $10.73
1073
Quarters: 42, remainder: 23
dimes: 2, remainder: 3
**nickels: 4195856, remainder: 3**
pennies: 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{

    float userinput;
    int cents, count, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies, remainder;

    printf("Please enter amount of change owed in $xx.xx format: $");
    scanf("%f",&userinput);

    while ((userinput <= 0) || (userinput < 0.01))
    {
        printf("Please enter a value equal to or greater than $0.01: $");
        scanf("%f",&userinput);
    }

    cents = roundf(userinput * 100);
    printf("%d\n", cents);

    while ((cents / 25) >= 1) {

        quarters = cents / 25;
        remainder = cents % 25;
        break;
    }

    printf("Quarters: %d, remainder: %d\n", quarters, remainder);

    while ((remainder / 10) >= 1) {

        dimes = remainder / 10;
        remainder = remainder % 10;
        break;
    }

        printf("dimes: %d, remainder: %d\n", dimes, remainder);

    while ((remainder / 5) >= 1) {

        nickels = remainder / 5;
        remainder = remainder % 5;
        break;
    }

    printf("nickels: %d, remainder: %d\n", nickels, remainder);

    while ((remainder / 1) >= 1) {

        pennies = remainder / 1;
        break;
    }

    printf("pennies: %d\n", pennies);
}
```

Comment: Initialize value of nickels at declaration of the same to 0

Comment: In your input ```10.73``` It is not going to the loop where nickels values is being modified so its just printing garbage value when you print it without initializing the variable and then if you don't change in in between code... So declare nickels like ```int nickels=0;```.This will solve the problem.

Comment: Note: Using `cents = roundf(userinput * 100);` is a _good_ step, handling money in whole units.  Note that `float` will begin to have issues with values above $100000.00 or so.  Recommend using `double userinput`.  Of course not much of an issue when using  small amounts like quarters, nickels, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your variables.

```
while ((remainder / 5) >= 1) {   // If "(remainder / 5) >= 1" is false

    nickels = remainder / 5;     // nickles is never set
    remainder = remainder % 5;
    break;
}

printf("nickels: %d, remainder: %d\n", nickels, remainder);  // Use of uninitialized value -> UB
```

So try to do:

```
int cents=0, count=0, quarters=0, dimes=0, nickels=0, pennies=0, remainder=0;
```

In general I think you should use `if` instead of `while`

```
int nickels = 0;

....
....

if ((remainder / 5) >= 1) {

    nickels = remainder / 5;
    remainder = remainder % 5;
}
```

BTW: When using `scanf` always check the return value.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Aren't the variables already initialized when they are declared outside a function, globally ie. int x  without an assigned value?

Comment: Yes but you declare them inside a function, i.e. `main` so they will not be initialized automatically.

Comment: @4386427 Copy & Paste is your friend and your enemy simultaneously!

Answer (score 2):

Automatic variables which are not initialized explicitly are NOT auto-initialized to zero.

Do

```
int nickels = 0; // similary for other variables too.
```

else you may get a `garbage value` - provided `nickels` is not set en route -  which may be very high :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you don't initialize the variable "nickeles".
So the initial value of "nickels" is range over than int value.
Also "remainder" is small than 5, so this instrument skipped.
So the value of "nickels" doesn't still change.
But you print the value of "nickels" to int type.

```
printf("nickels: %d, remainder: %d\n", nickels, remainder);
```

So the value of "nickels" was 4195856.

If you print the right value of "nickels", you must initialize the value of "nickels".

```
int nickels = 0;
```

I recommend that you will initialize all values in c/c++ when coding.

I hope this helps.